# Google Pub/Sub simple way to re-publish filtered subscription messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a simple say in Google Pub/Sub to re-publish messages from a filtered subscription?  This could be done using Dataflow, but it seems like a common enough thing that it might be specifically supported.

Comment: What do you mean by filtered messages? Do you want to replay the same message as before? Or do you want to play the messages excluded by the filter?

Comment: I have several subscriptions, each of which is filtering away 99% of the messages.  Creating a new topic would reduce load/cost and clarify the statistics.  I think I will create a separate topic and have the publisher cross-publish those events to that topic instead of filtering at the subscriber.

Comment: I think it's better to create a subscription without any filtering. You will have the same result.

Comment: In my opinion, [Google cloud dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) is a good choice because it handles real-time data processing, scalable, and is easy to use. Take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter) also.